# Choice of 32 bit or 64 bit Ubuntu for notebook

Tags: hardware

I have HP notebook with AMD Turion 64x2 processor with NVIDIA GeForce Go 6150 display adaptor. Which Ubuntu I can use 32 bit or 64 bit to dual boot with Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

Your processor is a 64 bit processor so I would just install a 64 bit version of ubuntu. What you do want to watch out for is your optimus enabled graphical card. you'll need bumblebee to get it to work correctly.
Now it has come to my attention that ubuntu 13.10 will have support for optimus graphical cards but my source isn't an official one so if someone can confirm this.

ubuntu 13.10 will be released next month (oct 2013) if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You neglected to mention how much memory your system has. The biggest advantage of 64-bit is the ability to use more than 4 GB of RAM. The tradeoff is that 64-bit code uses up more memory.

So despite your processor being 64-bit, I would choose 32-bit Ubuntu only if you really need it (i.e. if you have 4 GB RAM or more). If your system has only 2-3 GB RAM or less, you will get no benefit from 64-bit and it will actually be a bit slower.

Comment: 64 bit is actually faster because it can operate on larger numbers in a single cycle. This is especially useful for math-intensive things like video encoding.

Comment: True, however the impact from virtual memory thrashing if you use 64-bit on a low-memory system can definitely negate that advantage.